# Apply major/minor/patch automerge logic to SHA pinned dependencies with Renovate

Tags: github, dependency-management, renovate, automerge

I am using Renovate on a GitHub repository to keep dependencies up to date.
I want to automerge patches and minor releases, but I want to let minor releases ripen for a few days, using the `stabilityDays` setting. This seemed to be working with this config:

```yaml
  "minor": {
    "automerge": true,
    "stabilityDays": 3,
    "prCreation": "not-pending"
  },
  "patch": {
    "automerge": true,
    "stabilityDays": 0
  },
  "major": {
    "automerge": false
  },
```

I turned on security code scanning in my repo with "Scorecards" using the `ossf/scorecard-action` and the security scanning turned up some findings with helpful mitigation paths.  One of the suggestions was to use the SHA digest values to pin Docker dependencies instead of version numbers.

For example,

```yaml
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

becomes

```yaml
        uses: actions/checkout@d0651293c4a5a52e711f25b41b05b2212f385d28
```

That feels safer, so I like that.  But now the renovate PRs are not automerging like they used to and Renovate-bot leaves me this message in a PR that would have automerged when I was not using SHA digests:

```
 Automerge: Disabled by config. Please merge this manually once you are satisfied.
```

when before  it would say:

```
 Automerge: Enabled.
```

How can I configure Renovate to support better security and less noise and less manual intervention, while not allowing automerging of major versions?

I think that

```yaml
  "digest": {
    "automerge": true,
    "stabilityDays": 3,
    "prCreation": "not-pending"
  },
```

would turn on automerge for dependencies pinned by SHA digest keys, but now I think major version changes would be automerged, and I *do not* want that.

I have pored over the [docs](https://docs.renovatebot.com/automerge-configuration/) and other SO posts and could not winkle out a fix.

How can I have the serenity of SHA pinning *and* the convenience of minor and patch automerging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is that you **can** configure Renovate to follow your preferred major/minor/patch automerge logic when using SHA digest versions to pin dependencies.

The trick is the use of a comment after dependency digest version.

So, if you want to not automerge major version changes, and you want to give minor updates a three day stability period and you want to automerge patches quickly, all while pinning with digests, you could have this in your `renovate.json` configuration:

```yaml
   "minor": {
    "automerge": true,
    "stabilityDays": 3,
    "prCreation": "not-pending"
  },
  "patch": {
    "automerge": true,
  },
  "major": {
    "automerge": false
  },
  "digest": {
    "automerge": true
  },
```

Then go about pinning with the `tag=<version>` comment command like this, where we use a digest to pin the verion of `actions/checkout@v3` in a GitHub action workflow:

```yaml
 - uses: actions/checkout@2541b1294d2704b0964813337f33b291d3f8596b # v3.0.2
```

The presence of the version comment with the digest pin tells Renovatebot to respect any major/minor/patch automerge logic and to keep the version in the comment up to date with the digest version.

Thanks to @viceice on the [Renovatebot discussion board](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/15880) for pointing me to this answer.  It's been working great for me.

You can see this syntax in practice at https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/blob/a9a81275bf1fa40a4ba986601ab9fefd13fc9d41/.github/workflows/build.yml#L57

Comment: The [StepSecurity app](https://app.stepsecurity.io/) is a great tool for finding the SHA pins for your actions.